# Should frontend application know about distributed transaction (saga) state?

Tags: apache-kafka, microservices, distributed-transactions, event-driven-design

we have a bunch of spring webservices and a angular application in frontend

i am trying to implement choreography based saga, where a http req from frontend application to one of the service and the service will update its database and raise kafka event which will be listened by next webservice and so on

I am confused over the fact that should frontend assume the req is successful (what if saga fails in between and saga is rolled back)or wait till entire saga is completed

Any comments/suggestion around this would be helpful...

Comment: An Async process should have retries or reprocessing and after the exhausted attempt should move the messages to the Dead Letter Q. From where you should have options for the users to analyze and troubleshoot. From UI prespective, if you don;t need a immediate feedback in the UI then the action should be assumed success and async should continue in background.